# How to create a signature in Thunderbird in Mac OSX?

Tags: mac, thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird for sending the mail in Mac OS X. Now I want to know, how to create the signatures into the Thunderbird. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this article from the MozillaZine Knowledge Base:

> [Signatures - Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Signatures_%28Thunderbird%29)

In the article, it shows several ways to create signatures in Mozilla Thunderbird.